# most convenient way to represent a vector of vector references

Tags: c++, reference, stdvector

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;

using float_vec = vector<float>;

float foo( vector<float_vec*> vec )
{
  // ...

  return (*vec[0])[0] = 1;
}


int main()
{
  std::vector<float> i_1(1,0);
  // ...
  std::vector<float> i_n(1,0);

  std::cout << i_1[ 0 ] << std::endl;

  foo( {&i_1, /* ..., */ &i_n} );

  std::cout << i_1[ 0 ] << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

As you can see above, I pass a vector of float vectors to a function foo where here, foo has side effects on its input. For this, I use a vector of pointers; unfortunately this makes the code a bit unreadable -> "(*vec[0])[0]" and "&i_1",...,"&i_n". Is there a more elegant way to represent a vector of pointers in C++?

I tried to use std::refrence_wrappers as follows

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;

using float_vec = std::reference_wrapper< vector<float> >;

float foo( vector<float_vec> vec )
{
  // ...

  return vec[0].get()[0] = 1;
}


int main()
{
  std::vector<float> i_1(1,0);
  // ...
  std::vector<float> i_n(1,0);

  std::cout << i_1[ 0 ] << std::endl;

  foo( {i_1, /* ..., */ i_n} );

  std::cout << i_1[ 0 ] << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

however, here, the "get()" annoys.

Has anyone a suggestion for how a "vector of pointers/references" should be represented in C++?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to achieve is modify the vector you pass to the function, you don't need pointers. Just pass the vector by reference.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;

using float_vec = vector<float>;

float foo( vector<float_vec>& vec )
{
  // anything you do to vec here will change the vector you pass to the function

  return 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you provide a code example which demonstrates how the vectors "i_1", ..., "i_n" (of my example) have to be inserted in (the vector of your example) "float_vec"?

Comment: @abraham_hilbert Not right now. However, it's quite simple. Just call it with your object (vector) as a parameter, and then any modification you do inside that function will be done in the original vector.